# FacebookDialog sharing OpenGraphObject dismisses

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

I'm trying to implement a sharing dialog, but I have a weird problem. The dialog shows ok, but after a few seconds, it disappears. I'm using a fragment, and the dialog is appearing after clicking on an ActionBar Icon. This is the code I'm using:

```
OpenGraphObject ogObj = OpenGraphObject.Factory.createForPost("app-namespace:object");
ogObj .setProperty("title", "My title!");
ogObj .setProperty("description", "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.");

OpenGraphAction action = GraphObject.Factory.create(OpenGraphAction.class);
action.setProperty("object", ogObj);

FacebookDialog shareDialog = new FacebookDialog.OpenGraphActionDialogBuilder(getActivity(), action, "app-namespace:action", "object")
                    .build();
uiHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(shareDialog.present());
```

Also, I'm having these 2 warning messages on the logcat:

1) Tracking new app call while one is still pending; cancelling pending call.

2) Warning: Sessionless Request needs token but missing either application ID or client token.

Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I am also running across a similar issue.  I don't know what is wrong and I don't see any errors being thrown on my end anymore.  Just a screen come up and then immediately close again.  Not sure what is going on. Did you make progress?